One Set of Credentials From CSV File Per Thread
I have a CSV file with 100 lines in it: usernames and passwords. The system under test does not allow one user to interact with the system from multiple sessions, so I need to make sure that each thread is using its own username. How do I do this?
In my current test, three are five thread groups, and each of them have 10 threads. I am using the following settings for the CSV file:

Recycle on EOF: false
Stop Thread of EOF: true
Sharing Mode: All Threads

I want each thread to pick up a set of credentials and keep using those credentials as it continues looping. The problem with this is that each time a thread enters a new loop iteration, it picks up new credentials, so the CSV file is exhausted fairly soon.

If you don't mind using JMeter Plugins there is Extended-csv-dataset-config where you can control when to update the values and pre-allocate blocks of values to virtual users.

The plugin can be installed using JMeter Plugins Manager
